# convert datetime to float in R

Tags: r, datetime

I want to convert a datetime variable in R into a decimal with 10 digits after the point.
I tried this:

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x = "2019-01-01 02:10:00",tz = "UTC"))/(60*60*24)
[1] 17897.09
```

but I am expecting to get this : 17897.0944444444

Comment: Why are you expecting this?

Comment: well, I'm using an R package that internally do a lot of calculations, and one of them is convering datetime to numeric value. And this is the result for that date.

Comment: Well, there is an offset by 6 minutes from that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not assigning the calculation to a new variable and just printing to the console, it might appear that your number is truncated when it actually isn't.

For instance:

```
numeric_date <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x = "2019-01-01 02:10:00",tz = "UTC"))
val <- (60*60*24)
total <- numeric_date/val
print(total)
```

Gives us:

```
> print(total)
[1] 17897.09028
```

If you use `sprintf("%.10f", total)`, you can specify that you want a floating number with 10 digit decimal precision.

This gives us:

```
> sprintf("%.10f", total)
[1] "17897.0902777778"
```

This is also the actual value that can be seen in your environment, under the `Values` heading.

Comment: When exporting this results to textfile, I always get 17897.09

Comment: But that's not OP's expected value. It's different by 6 minutes.